# wix react native navigation single screen app in portrait mode on Android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

I am developing a React Native App for iOS and Android using [wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/).

I am using

- `react-native@0.55.4`
- `react-native-navigation@^1.1.478`

While researching how to force an Android App into portrait mode I found tons of answers basically saying either of these two options is the way to go:

1. Adjust the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

2. Set the orientation programmatically in the `MainActivity.java`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

But neither has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the used version of RNN the docs state that a tab-based app `appStyle` can contain `orientation: "portrait"` so I just tried it out for my single screen app and it worked!

```
import {Navigation} from "react-native-navigation"

Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    appStyle: {
        orientation: "portrait",
    },
    screen: {
        // ...
    },
    passProps: {},
    animationType: "fade",
})
```